# Adobe Air: Error 307

Tags: android, flash, air, adobe

I made a little flash game and I am trying to export it into an APK to use it on Android, this is my first "project" so this is completely new to me, this is my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<application xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/2.5">
    <id>com.rockpaperguitars.test1</id>
    <versionNumber>1.0.0</versionNumber>
    <filename>test1</filename>
    <description>just a test</description>
    <name>tablature game</name>
    <copyright>Ryan S</copyright>
    <initialWindow>
        <content>test1.swf</content>
        <visible>true</visible>
        <fullScreen>true</fullScreen>
        <autoOrients>false</autoOrients>
            <systemChrome>standard</systemChrome>
    <transparent>false</transparent>
        <aspectRatio>landscape</aspectRatio>
        <renderMode>gpu</renderMode>
    </initialWindow>
    <customUpdateUI>false</customUpdateUI>
    <allowBrowserInvocation>false</allowBrowserInvocation>
    <icon>
        <image36x36>icon36.png</image36x36>
        <image48x48>icon48.png</image48x48>
        <image72x72>icon72.png</image72x72>
    </icon>
    <android>
        <manifestAdditions><![CDATA[<manifest>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/></manifest>
]]></manifestAdditions>
    </android>
    <versionLabel>1</versionLabel>
</application>
```

I then tried to package it all using:

```
adt -package -target apk -storetype pkcs12 -keystore TestFlashAndroidApp.p12 Tablature.apk TestflashAndroidApp.xml test1.swf icon36.png icon48.png icon72.png
```

But I am getting this error:

```
error 301: application descriptor must be at least namespace 3.0
```

Can you tell me what I am doing wrong please?

Comment: change this line <application xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/2.5"> to <application xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/3.0"> and see if it works

Comment: Thanks! I got a new message, see the comment below

Comment: this is not an error I believe. Try installing your APK and se if it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this line 
`<application xmlns="ns.adobe.com/air/application/2.5">;` 
to 
`<application xmlns="ns.adobe.com/air/application/3.0">;`

and see if it works

Comment: Thanks! Any idea why I am getting the below message though?

Comment: testNOTE: The AIR SDK no longer supports packaging android with the shared Runtime. The application has been packaged with a captive Runtime.

Comment: the earlier models of AIR were using shared Runtime , whereas after the recent updates Adobe has moved on to captive Runtime. Could be that you might not be having the latest AIR update.

Comment: I just downloaded the AIR SDK from Adobe, but I am using Flash CS6 and selected Air 3.4 in it... do you recommend something else?

Comment: check this link http://blogs.adobe.com/airodynamics/2013/03/11/android-shared-runtime-drop-support/

Answer (score 2):

The XML file you posted above is called the application descriptor. The namespace number of the file format is shown in the first node -

```
<application xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/2.5">
```

You need to change this number to match the version of the AIR compiler you are using. You're likely using version 3.0 or above, which is why you're seeing that message. Change the number to 3.0 instead of 2.5 and it should work fine.